# Rails App with Sinatra engine - How to avoid rails errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sinatra, rails-engines

Problem: When running specs the output is very confusing, instead of saying where the error lies it just throws misleading errors

This is inside the rails lib folder, and it's mounted on the routes.rb

```
# lib/engines/users/app.rb

module Engines
  module Users
    class App < Sinatra::Base
        get '/api/v1/users/me' do
          raise 'runtime error here'
        end

        get '/api/v1/another-route' do
          # something here
          status 200
        end
    end
  end
end
```

The spec file looks something like this:

```
it 'returns a 200' do
  get '/api/v1/users/me', auth_attributes
  expect(last_response.body).to eq 'something' # added to clarify my point, it's not the response status that I care of.
  expect(last_response.status).to be 200
end
```

error:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(last_response.status).to be 200

   expected #<Fixnum:401> => 200
        got #<Fixnum:1001> => 500

   Compared using equal?, which compares object identity,
   but expected and actual are not the same object. Use
   `expect(actual).to eq(expected)` if you don't care about
   object identity in this example.
```

expected error:

```
     RuntimeError:
       runtime error here
```

Another route also fails:

```
it 'something' do
  get '/api/v1/another-route', auth_attributes
  expect(last_response.status).to be 401
  json = JSON.parse(last_response.body).with_indifferent_access
  expect(json[:message]).to eql "You have been revoked access."
end
```

error: Prints a massive html output which I believe is the rails backtrace html output

expected error: none as this endpoint doesn't raise an error

My question is if there's a way to:

1. Stop rails from dealing with this, so it gives the actual output
2. Avoid the entire engine to fail because one route raise exception

I believe that by solving the first point, the second one gets fixed too.

Thank you for your time

Comment: `get '/api/v1/users/me'` goes to `raise 'runtime error here'` which would be an internal server error.  Which would give a response status of 500, which you're getting.

Comment: In a vanilla sinatra app that will actually return ` RuntimeError: runtime error here`

Comment: But your spec is looking at the status code.  If I copy your sinatra code and go to it in chrome, viewing the headers I get a status code of 500.  You're not checking the body, which is where it outputs RuntimeError

Comment: I've forgot to add that, but you get the point. I've updated the code so it should be clear now.

Comment: I'm afraid that's still confusing.  You still have the error as it expecting 200, but it returns 500.  Based on your updated snippet `expect(last_response.body).to eq 'something'` this passes.  You wouldn't get your expected error if that is what your test is expecting, it will simply pass the test.

Comment: Check my answer, what was returning was an html page with backtrace, because it was in development mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve my problem I've discovered that on the `spec_helper` the `ENV['RACK_ENV']` was not being set, setting it to `test` resolves the problem and throws the exception I need in order to debug my code.

This happens because https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1832

`set :show_exceptions, Proc.new { development? }`

`development?` returned true when in fact should be false (needed the `RACK_ENV` set to test)

Now I get the correct output.